# I want .fadeout every div expect .this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want that every div classed "**insegnanti**" fadeout except the one that i clicked

The script:

```
for(var i=0;i<instructor.length;i++){
  $(document).on ("click", ".insegnanti#i"+[i+1], loadSingleIns);
 el+="<div class='insegnanti' id='i"+instructor[i].id+"'><img src='"+instructor[i].th_image+"'><div class='desc'>"+instructor[i].name+" "+instructor[i].surname+"</div></div>";   
}
```

**my func:**

```
function loadSingleIns(){
   i = this.id.replace('i','');

  $(".insegnanti:not(this)").fadeOut( "fast" );

$(this).animate({
 opacity: 1,
 left: "+=50",
 width: "50%",   
 height: "50%",   
  }, 5000, function() {
// Animation complete.
 });


}
```

I tried use `$(".insegnanti:not(this)").fadeOut( "fast" )` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `".insegnanti:not(.this)"`

Comment: Let me know if none of the answers helped or you are still facing trouble

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, try [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(".insegnanti").not(this).fadeOut( "fast" );
```

When you did `$(".insegnanti:not(this)")` it will not parse `this` in the string as the *contextual* object. Rather, it will use it as some sort of sub-selector(which wont work in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way. `$( "selector" ).not( "selector" )` - is the syntax. Try with -

```
$(".insegnanti").not(this).fadeOut( "fast" );
```

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)